# Binding multiple column pairs into 1 column efficiently

Tags: r

I've configured the data how I needed but it took 15 lines of code. I was sure it could be done in 1 or 2, and I'm hoping someone a lot better at this can teach me how. Here it is...

I have a table with 11 variables that consists of a Date, 4 pairs of spread and price observations, followed by the year and quarter corresponding to the data column. The 4 pairs of data each correspond to different TBA mortgage coupons (3%, 3.5%, 4%, 4.5%).

[mbstrimlast table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zowG9.jpg)

I need the 8 columns to be in 2 columns named ZSpread and Price, and then each pair tagged with the coupon Type.

Here's the code I used. Thanks!

```
mbs3 <- mbstrimlast[,c("Date",ZSpread="FN3sprd",Price="FN3px")]
names(mbs3) <- c("Date","Zspread","Price")
mbs3.5 <- mbstrimlast[,c("Date",ZSpread="FN3.5sprd",Price="FN3.5px")]
names(mbs3.5) <- c("Date","Zspread","Price")
mbs4 <- mbstrimlast[,c("Date",ZSpread="FN4sprd",Price="FN4px")]
names(mbs4) <- c("Date","Zspread","Price")
mbs4.5 <- mbstrimlast[,c("Date",ZSpread="FN4.5sprd",Price="FN4.5px")]
names(mbs4.5) <- c("Date","Zspread","Price")

mbs3$Type = c("FN3")
mbs3.5$Type = c("FN3.5")
mbs4$Type = c("FN4")
mbs4.5$Type = c("FN4.5")

mbslast = bind_rows(mbs3, mbs3.5, mbs4, mbs4.5)
mbslast <- mbslast %>% mutate(Yeartag = year(mbslast$Date))
mbslast <- mbslast %>% mutate(Qtag = quarters(mbslast$Date, abbreviate = T))
```

Comment: So you don't actually have a question, you just want someone to write better code for you? In general, SO is not the place to ask for that kind of advice. I would encourage you to browse a few `tidyverse` tutorials, or post this to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is a helpful StackExchange site.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to move it there. My question is, what's the right way to do this. I feel like I brute forced it. "better code" is really always the question that people seem to be asking here.

Comment: I apologize for getting snippy, I think I can help clean up your code. Could you post a reproducible example of your data? using `dput(head(mbstrimlast, 1))` should be sufficient

Comment: No problem. `> dput(head(mbstrimlast,1))
structure(list(Date = structure(1529294400, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), FN3sprd = 52.8, FN3.5sprd = 67.7, FN4sprd = 81.9, 
    FN4.5sprd = 87.2, FN3px = 96.35938, FN3.5px = 99.10938, FN4px = 101.64844, 
    FN4.5px = 103.89062, Yeartag = 2018, Qrts = "Q2"), .Names = c("Date", 
"FN3sprd", "FN3.5sprd", "FN4sprd", "FN4.5sprd", "FN3px", "FN3.5px", 
"FN4px", "FN4.5px", "Yeartag", "Qrts"), row.names = 2501L, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I was trying to use gather, but it was beyond me. I'm going to have to hit my head against what you've done here to fully grasp. Amazing however, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `tidyverse` package to make the code to complete this task a bit cleaner. First, we use `gather` to reshape from wide to long, then we create `type` and `key` columns using `grepl` and `gsub`, finally, we use `spread` to get the data back into a tidier format.

```
library(tidyverse)

mbstrimlast %>%
    gather(variable, value, -Date, -Yeartag, -Qrts) %>% # wide to long
    # column creation
    mutate(type = ifelse(grepl(pattern = 'sprd', x = variable), 'Spread', 'Price'),
           key = gsub(pattern = 'sprd|px', replacement = '', x = variable)) %>%
    select(-variable) %>% # remove variable column
    spread(type, value) # tidier

                 Date Yeartag Qrts   key     Price Spread
1 2018-06-17 23:00:00    2018   Q2   FN3  96.35938   52.8
2 2018-06-17 23:00:00    2018   Q2 FN3.5  99.10938   67.7
3 2018-06-17 23:00:00    2018   Q2   FN4 101.64844   81.9
4 2018-06-17 23:00:00    2018   Q2 FN4.5 103.89062   87.2
```